# Get All In One SEO Pack to use custom field instead of Content

Tags: php, seo, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having an issue with a custom theme whereby All in One SEO pack isn't auto-generating descriptions because I am using a custom field to enter the main body of the page/post. Is there way to specify that All in One SEO uses a specific field to read from for the purpose of generating the SEO content automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not specify which field, but you can use the filter *aioseop_description* to do whatever you want with the description before presenting. So technically, you can use your custom field as follows (untested) :

```
add_filter('aioseop_description','my_custom_description');
global $post;
function my_custom_description($text) {
$mycustomseo = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_custom_field', true);
return $mycustomseo;
}
```

Replace *my_custom_field* with your custom field.

Source Ref : http://4coder.info/en/blog/2011/all-in-one-seo-pack-customization/

Comment: Thanks for the help, where would I place this code - in functions.php?

Comment: Ben, yes that is correct.